# Login Pop Up button pops up automatically and won't go directly to login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble editing the jquery and html to make the login button pop up the login form instead of showing another login button. Also for some reason the login button is popping up on load.

http://jsfiddle.net/1s3gycd8/

I'm new to Jquery and I'm posting question after attempting to solve this problem with no avail. If any of you have the answer to my question please respond with the changes in the code or even better update the jsfiddle. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Login</a>
    <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
        <header class="popupHeader">
            <span class="header_title">Login</span>
            <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </header>
        <section class="popupBody">
            <!-- Social Login -->
            <div class="social_login">
                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn">Login</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Username & Password Login form -->
            <div class="user_login">
                <form>
                    <label>Email / Username</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Register Form -->
            <div class="user_register">
                <form>
                    <label>Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="send_updates">Send me occasional email updates</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5,
                closeButton: null
            };
            var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var o = options;
                var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");

                function showModal() {
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });

                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();

                    $("#lean_overlay").css({
                        "display": "block",
                        opacity: 0
                    });

                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);

                    $(modal_id).css({
                        "display": "block",
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "z-index": 11000,
                        "left": 50 + "%",
                        "margin-left": -(modal_width / 2) + "px",
                        "top": o.top + "px"
                    });

                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
                };

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    showModal();
                });

                $(this).click(function (e) {
                    showModal();
                    e.preventDefault()
                })
            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);



$("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

    $(function(){
        // Calling Login Form
        $("#login_form").click(function(){
            $(".social_login").hide();
            $(".user_login").show();
            return false;
        });

    })
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,700italic,400italic);

body {font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;}

#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}

.popupContainer{
    position:absolute;
    width:330px;
    height: auto;
    left:45%;
    top:80px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#modal_trigger {margin:100px auto; width:100px; display:block;}

.btn {padding:10px 20px; background: #F4F4F2;}
.btn_red {background: #ED6347; color: #FFF;}

.btn:hover {background: #E4E4E2;}
.btn_red:hover {background: #C12B05;}

a.btn {color:#666; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;}
a.btn_red {color: #FFF;}

.one_half {width:50%; display: block; float:left;}
.one_half.last {width:45%; margin-left:5%;}

/* Popup Styles*/
.popupHeader {font-size:16px; text-transform: uppercase;}
.popupHeader {background:#F4F4F2; position:relative; padding:10px 20px; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD; font-weight:bold;}
.popupHeader .modal_close {position: absolute; right: 0; top:0; padding:10px 15px; background:#E4E4E2; cursor: pointer; color:#aaa; font-size:16px;}

.popupBody {padding:20px;}


/* Social Login Form */
.social_login {}
.social_login .social_box {display:block; clear:both; padding:10px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: #F4F4F2; overflow: hidden;}
.social_login .icon {display:block; width:10px; padding:5px 10px; margin-right: 10px; float:left; color:#FFF; font-size:16px; text-align: center;} 
.social_login .fb .icon {background:#3B5998;}
.social_login .google .icon {background:#DD4B39;}
.social_login .icon_title {display:block; padding:5px 0; float:left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color:#777;}
.social_login .social_box:hover {background: #E4E4E2;}

.centeredText {text-align: center; margin: 20px 0; clear: both; overflow: hidden; text-transform: uppercase;}

.action_btns {clear:both; overflow: hidden;}
.action_btns a {display: block;}

/* User Login Form */
.user_login {display: none;}
.user_login label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_login input[type="text"], .user_login input[type="email"], .user_login input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; margin-right:5px;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}

.user_login .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
.forgot_password {display:block; margin: 20px 0 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none; color:#ED6347;}

/* User Register Form */
.user_register {display: none;}
.user_register label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_register input[type="text"], .user_register input[type="email"], .user_register input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; margin-right:5px;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}

.user_register .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed a method (and some very small other changes, see DEMO):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     showModal();
});
```

DEMO: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s3gycd8/3/)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will compare the fiddles and keep on learning jquery, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the initial display correctly, like this:

```
.social_login {display: none;}
.user_login {display: block;}
```

But you should review all your code, seems to be that there are many things left over.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/1s3gycd8/1/